# CSS gradient checkerboard pattern

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I want to create a checkerboard pattern using gradients. I've found an example and modified it to my needs, however it only works with `-moz` prefix. When I remove the `-moz` prefix, the pattern is completely different. [image: comparison of patterns : normal vs. -moz]

How can I make this `-moz` checkerboard pattern work with unprefixed `linear-gradient`?

```
body {
  background-image:
  linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), 
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%),
  linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%);

  background-size:20px 20px;    
  background-position:0 0, 10px 0, 10px -10px, 0px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Use Autoprefixer (with npm, gulp, grunt, via Prepros 4, any tool really) and you won't have any problem with prefixes ever. Or else caniuse.com is the reference for this sort of things (search "gradient" and then click "View all (versions)" button)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55455177/8620333

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Just modify the `background-position` like in the below snippet to get the required output. This works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE11 and Edge.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #808080 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #808080 75%);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 10px, 10px -10px, -10px 0px;
}
```

The problem seems to be happening because of a difference in the way the angles are handled by the `-moz` linear gradient and the standard one.  `-45deg` in the `-moz` linear gradient seems to be equal to `135deg` in the standard gradient (*but changing the angle is resulting in a strange dot in the middle*).

The below screenshots show the difference (both taken in the latest Firefox v44.0).

**Output with -moz-linear-gradient:**

[image]

**Output with linear gradient:**

[image]

Answer (score 106):

It's 2020 and this can now be created with a single CSS gradient (if you don't need to support IE/ pre-Chromium Edge).

```css
html {
  background: 
    repeating-conic-gradient(#808080 0% 25%, transparent 0% 50%) 
      50% / 20px 20px
}
```

I wrote a [detailed explanation on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/background-patterns-simplified-by-conic-gradients/#checkerboard) for how this works.

Comment: Cool way to make it.Is there a fallback for IE and non support browser ?

Comment: @Lorenzo Judging from what Ana wrote I would guess the fallback is just to use multiple CSS gradients like all the other answers do.

Comment: Looks like it's a little off in Chrome: https://i.imgur.com/qswaMXH.png

Answer (score 38):

The 45deg version works nicely, but can end up showing a line between the triangles at different zoom levels or on retina screens. Depending on what browsers you need to support you can also use `background-blend-mode: difference` ([Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode) currently shows support nearly everywhere except IE), you can tint the checks using an additional background image:

```css
body {
    background-image: /* tint image */
                      linear-gradient(to right, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.75), rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.75)),
                      /* checkered effect */
                      linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%),
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50%, white 50%);
    background-blend-mode: normal, difference, normal;
    background-size: 2em 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This was Chrome's implementation for when you opened an image with transparency for a while (though they later removed it in favor of just using a solid background).

```css
body {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 10px 10px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%),linear-gradient(45deg, #eee 25%, white 25%, white 75%, #eee 75%, #eee 100%);
}
```

Comment: @mix3d When I first looked at this change, my laptop's brightness was apparently too dim to show the background effect, so it didn't appear "how it would look". Now that I'm on a desktop monitor, I see the slight checkered effect; rolled back.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Harry for the inspiration - here's an scss mixin to do that

```
@mixin checkers($size: 50px, $contrast: 0.07) {
  $checkerColor: rgba(#000, $contrast);
  $angle: 45deg;
  $tp: 25%;

  background-image: linear-gradient($angle, $checkerColor $tp, transparent $tp),
    linear-gradient(-$angle, $checkerColor $tp, transparent $tp),
    linear-gradient($angle, transparent 3 * $tp, $checkerColor 3 * $tp),
    linear-gradient(-$angle, transparent 3 * $tp, $checkerColor 3 * $tp);
  background-size: $size $size;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 $size/2, $size/2 -1 * $size/2, -1 * $size/2 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the "checkerboard pattern by linear gradients" can produce ugly artifacts

gif checkerboard pattern

```html
<body style="

/* keep it sharp on zoom and dpi scaling */
image-rendering: pixelated;

/* 10px dark checkerboard pattern: 70% black + 80% black */
background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKAKECADAwMEdHR15eXl5eXiH5BAEKAAIALAAAAAAKAAoAAAIRhB2ZhxoM3GMSykqd1VltzxQAOw==);

"></body>
```

gif is 10x smaller than png: 50 versus 500 bytes