# Fallback to checkerboard if var(--color) is undefined

Tags: css, css-variables

How can I make it so that when `--color` is  set, it overrides the checkerboard background?

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054396/65387 */
  background-image: /* tint image */
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9), rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9)), /* checkered effect */
  linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50%, white 50%);
  background-blend-mode: normal, difference, normal;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.a {
  background-color: var(--color);
}

.b {
  background: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cell a">a1</div>
  <div class="cell a" style="--color:red;">a2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="cell b">b1</div>
  <div class="cell b" style="--color:red;">b2</div>
</div>
```

`a2` doesn't override the background like I want.

`b2` does, but then `b1` becomes white.

Is there a way to do this without JavaScript?

Comment: `b1` becomes white because `--color` isn't defined in the stylesheet. If you added `:root { --color: red; }` to your CSS then both `b1` and `b2` would be red.

Comment: @TannerDolby Right... that's the whole question. I only want it to fallback when it's not defined.

Comment: Got it. Hmm let me think here. `@supports` won't work because we don't care if the browser supports CSS custom properties, we're only concerned with the custom property being defined or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`var()` second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#custom_property_fallback_values) that works if the variable isn't defined.

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054396/65387 */
  
  background-blend-mode: normal, difference, normal;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}



.b {
  background-image:/* tint image */
  linear-gradient(to right, var(--color,rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9)), var(--color,rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9))), /* checkered effect */
  linear-gradient(to right, var(--color,black 50%),var(--color,white 50%)),     linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--color,black 50%), var(--color,white 50%));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cell b">b1</div>
  <div class="cell b" style="--color:red;">b2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an extra layer like below:

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: 
    linear-gradient(var(--color,transparent) 0 0), /* the extra layer */
    linear-gradient(rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0 0),
    linear-gradient(to right,  black 50%, white 0), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50%, white 0);
  background-blend-mode:normal, normal, difference, normal;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">a1</div>
<div class="cell" style="--color:red;">a2</div>
<div class="cell" style="--color:blue;">b2</div>
```

You can also scale the solution to consider image too:

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: 
    var(--image,linear-gradient(transparent 0 0)), /* the extra image layer */
    linear-gradient(var(--color,transparent) 0 0), /* the extra color layer */
    linear-gradient(rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0 0),
    linear-gradient(to right,  black 50%, white 0) 0 0/25px 25px, 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50%, white 0) 0 0/25px 25px;
  background-blend-mode:normal, normal ,normal, difference, normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">a1</div>
<div class="cell" style="--color:red;">a2</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:linear-gradient(green,blue);">b2</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200) center/cover;">b3</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/18/50/50)  center no-repeat;--color:yellow">b4</div>
```

An optimized version with `conic-gradient` and without blend-mode

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: 
    var(--image,linear-gradient(transparent 0 0)), /* the extra image layer */
    linear-gradient(var(--color,transparent) 0 0), /* the extra color layer */
    linear-gradient(rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0 0),
    repeating-conic-gradient(#fff 0 90deg,#000 0 180deg) 0 0/25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">a1</div>
<div class="cell" style="--color:red;">a2</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:linear-gradient(green,blue);">b2</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200) center/cover;">b3</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/18/50/50)  center no-repeat;--color:yellow">b4</div>
```

Another idea using pseudo element:

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0 0),
    repeating-conic-gradient(#fff 0 90deg,#000 0 180deg) 0 0/25px 25px;
}
.cell::before,
.cell::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  inset:0;
}
.cell::before {
  background:var(--color);
}
.cell::after {
  background:var(--image);
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">a1</div>
<div class="cell" style="--color:red;">a2</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:linear-gradient(green,blue);">b2</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200) center/cover;">b3</div>
<div class="cell" style="--image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/18/50/50)  center no-repeat;--color:yellow">b4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using JavaScript, I think the only way to provide a custom fallback if `--color` isn't defined is by using a [fallback value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#custom_property_fallback_values).

Custom fallback values are just a backup for the browser which supports CSS Custom Properties to choose a different value if the given variable isn't **defined** or has an invalid value.

```
.a {
  background-image: var(--color, var(--checkerboard)); /* css var for linear-gradients */
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

So if the custom property `--color` isn't defined, the browser will use the fallback value. In this case, using a combination of `background-image` and `background-color` seems to do the trick.

It works by testing the `background-image` property to see if `--color` is defined. If it's not, then keep the checkerboard design by using the `linear-gradient` combination as the fallback value.

```css
:root {
  --checkerboard: /* tint image */
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9), rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9)), /* checkered effect */
  linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50%, white 50%);
}

.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51054396/65387 */
  background-image: var(--checkerboard); /* can be removed but then .a or .b will need to be defined */
  background-blend-mode: normal, difference, normal;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.a {
  background-image: var(--color, var(--checkerboard));
  background-color: var(--color);
}

.b {
  background-image: var(--color, var(--checkerboard));
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cell a">a1</div>
  <div class="cell a" style="--color: red;">a2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="cell b">b1</div>
  <div class="cell b" style="--color: red;">b2</div>
</div>
```