# Canvas with a transparent background, why am i getting this error? Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas in HTML and I am trying to put a transparent background so I can layer other elements under it. This is the advised code to enable a transparent background on a canvas.

```
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

<canvas style="width: 1500px; height: 800px;"></canvas>
```

Error message:  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Pls note that the title should be in question format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the canvas have a black background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71645601/why-does-the-canvas-have-a-black-background)

Comment: @ArchitGargi this does not answer the question, which answer specifically do you feel would solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are getting the error/exception due to the fact that [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a list instead of a single element.

I would propose/recommend using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

A sample would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<canvas id='canvas' width='600' height='300'>
</canvas>
```

JS:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I now have a new error: Cannot access 'ctx' before initialization

Comment: Are you using the ctx variable before it was declared? That error would return if it was the case

Comment: I have added the ID in a different JS file, do I need to make sure this is added after the canvas is created?     $('canvas').attr('id', 'canvas');

Comment: If you followed my example, you don’t necessarily have to do that. Because the canvas itself within the HTML canvas tag already has the canvas ID

Comment: the canvas is being created with WEBGL, so I will need to use js to add the class.