# CSS 4 color checkers background

Tags: css

I am trying to create 4 color checker background using linear gradient but not sure how can I fill the entire background with the checker.
Here is the current implementation:

Code

```css
.tab-content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%), linear-gradient(to right, green 50%, yellow 50%);
  background-size: 20px 10px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content"></div>
```

Also attaching the current implementation.
[Current implementation of checker background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lncQi.png)

Comment: Do you want 4 squares total? Or for that pattern to repeat? (Either your `background-repeat` or your `background-size` is incorrect)

Comment: can you post a working sandbox for that ?

Comment: I want the pattern to repeat across the whole background. I have tried,  background-repeat: repeat, repeat

Comment: use background-repeat

Comment: I guess, the author has already tried, background-repeat property. A fixed implementation is what they are looking for.

Comment: using conic-gradient `background: conic-gradient(blue 25%, yellow 0 50%, green 0 75%, red 0) 0 0/20px 20px;`  although IE doesn't support it

Comment: @Zohini That would make a good answer.

Comment: @Zohini Thanks it works perfectly. Is it not possible with multiple linear gradient ?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129916/8620333 and follow the link there to understand how conic-gradient works

Comment: I'm not sure about `linear-gradient` having four colors repeat is problematic, since position is sort of ignored, one of the colors will be stepped over, with conic, you basically define four colors in a single image, and have the whole thing repeat, which is far too simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using conic-gradient *although IE doesn't support it*

```css
body {
  background: conic-gradient(blue 25%, yellow 0 50%, green 0 75%, red 0) 0 0/20px 20px;
}
```