# Html special character background (no image, no string, no js)

Tags: html, css

I want to fill the entire (html) background with the special character below.
Is it possible only with css?

```css
html::before {
  content: '\2591';
}
```

This is still not enough..

Comment: Do you really just want to fill the background with a checker style pattern? Or do you specifically want to use that character?

Comment: Just for background

Comment: This uses linear-gradient to fill the background with checkers, you can change the size in the background position. Is that what you were looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35362074/3684265

Comment: No, that's not what I was looking for

Comment: You could create a 4x4 pixel bmp or png, convert it to a base64 data url and use it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rjfasmu7/2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
html {
  background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='25px' width='20px'><text x='0' y='15' fill='red' font-size='20'>░</text></svg>")
}
```

```html
<p>Example website content</p><p>Example website content</p><p>Example website content</p>
```

Comment: Looks ugly but clever answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

First repeat the character inside content a lot of times (use CSS variables to make the code shorter) then use filter to continue the repetition:

```css
html::before {
  --c: '\2591  \2591  \2591  \2591  \2591  \2591  ';
  content: 
    var(--c) var(--c) var(--c) var(--c) '\A'
    var(--c) var(--c) var(--c) var(--c) '\A'
    var(--c) var(--c) var(--c) var(--c) '\A';
  white-space: pre;
  line-height: 1.3;
  position: fixed;
  filter:
   drop-shadow(23em 0)
   drop-shadow(46em 0)
   drop-shadow(92em 0)
   drop-shadow(0 4em)
   drop-shadow(0 8em)
   drop-shadow(0 16em)
   drop-shadow(0 32em)
   drop-shadow(0 64em);
}
```